# I need an Emacs regular expression to find "for" loops

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to write an Emacs lisp function to find all the "for" loops in a C file and calculate their lengths.  I haven't found a regular expression that.   Will find all the "for" statements.  (Once I do it's easy to calculate the loop lengths.)  The regexp

```
"^[ \t]*for[ \t]*(.*\\;.*\\;.*)[:ascii:]*[^{\;]"
```

finds such as

```
for (a;b;d)  {

}
```

and

```
for (a;d;c) {ccc ;}
```

but not ones such as

```
for (a;b;c) xxxxxxxxx ;
```

or

```
for (a;b;c;)\n{

}
```

My current approach is to skip all the characters until encountering either a `;` or a `{`, using a looking-at function to decide which type of loop it is.

The regexp

```
^[ \t]*for[ \t]*(.*\\;.*\\;.*)[ \t\n]*[^{\;]
```

finds all the loops with braces but doesn't find the one-line loops without them.  I think that the first regexp should be better than this one, but it's not. (Once I get the "for" statements to work I'm going to move on to "while" loops, etc.)

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I guess this is generally not advisable, but maybe sth. like this helps: https://regex101.com/r/2J9zq1/2

Comment: Have you considered using the `\\|` to join several regexp that match apples and oranges?  E.g, `"apples\\|oranges\\|grapes\\|pears"`  If you have not already played with `M-x re-builder`, it is really helpful to play with different combinations and visually see what matches.

Comment: Regexps are not very useful for parsing programming languages in a general way.

Comment: As JZ said years ago:  _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._

Answer (score 4):

Trying to find a foolproof regular expression for this case is difficult, but you can instead take advantage of `cc-mode` functions to help navigate across code and also avoid counting anything inside a comment or macro.

I'm not exactly sure what you meant by "length" but the function below searches for a `for` loop and if it finds one, returns the distance between what it determines to be the end of the `for` loop and its beginning. If it finds no `for` loop, it returns `nil`. If by "length" you meant something else, you should be able to easily adapt the code to do what you want.

```
(defun for-loop-length ()
  (save-excursion
    (if (c-syntactic-re-search-forward "\\_<for\\_>" (point-max) t)
        (let ((start (match-beginning 0)))
          (c-skip-ws-forward)
          (forward-sexp)
          (c-skip-ws-forward)
          (if (char-equal (char-after) ?{)
              (forward-sexp)
            (c-end-of-statement))
          (- (point) start)))))
```

The `c-syntactic-re-search-forward` function automatically skips searching inside comments, string literals, and macros. The `c-skip-ws-forward` function handles skipping across horizontal and vertical whitespace. The `c-end-of-statement` function handles the case of a `for` loop without braces, finding the closing semicolon even if it's on another line.